# Masking out unwanted bits from array of uint64_t

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, vectorization, simd, intrinsics

I have an array of 8 uint64_t (512 bits).  I also receive 2 numbers as function parameters.
  Let them be 54 and 133.
  I need to mask out every bit with position (zero based) lower then 54 or higher then 133 .

**What is the most cost efficient way to do that?**

It would be easy to do so with one uint64_t.

```
int a=6;
int b=12;
uint64_t source=0xD0400000000000;
uint64_t mask=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
uint64_t result=source&((mask<<(a+63-b))>>a);//D0000000000000
```

But there is a problem with data larger then uint64_t (in this case an array).
  Also, another problem is when these bits i want to extract cross boundaries of multiple uint64_t's.
This code has to be really fast, so I have to avoid branches or any costly operations.

Is there a way to implement it with intrinsics to make it perform fast?

Comment: 64-bit integers are the largest integer types in standard C++, there are no larger types. If you have an array, it's actually not a larger value, it's a set of equal (or smaller) types. If you want to use larger types look a a tignum library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: The only problem with doing it in an array is you haven't yet done the math to determine which slots have to be modified, then written the code to do so. Perhaps try that and see if it performs as well as you need (and it should likely take less time than it did to write this question).

Comment: @WhozCraig I know a naive way to do that. Check for every array slot if it's within 'a' and 'b' boundaries. Lets take for example 3rd long long. Its boundaries are 128-191. If it isn't within boundaries set mask to 0. Else, compute max(128,a)-a as new lowest bound,min(191,b)-128 as upper bound. Then check for every slot as in example above. But this is too slow. I was hoping that there is a way to user vectorization or something similar to get better results and avoid branching.

Comment: Not exactly how I'd approach it, but that would be one way. I would rather compute the range of affected slots, set them ALL to lit minus the (potentially two) end slots, then modify the (potentially two) slot(s)s that need cleaning up, and call it good. At least you understand the problem, however, which is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you like it or not, you'll need special handling for the
first and the last array element involved, with `if`.
Basically, you have to convert your first and last into
bit-number/array index pairs, and work from there.  To mask out
everything but the designated range, you zap everything beloe
the first array index, and after the last (probably using 
`std::fill`), and special handle the elements at the first and
last array index (which may be the same, which in turn entails
special handling, different from the case where they are
different).  Very roughly (and without any error handling):

```
//  quot is element index,
//  rem is bit number in element.
div_t first = div( firstBitNumber, bitsInWord );
div_t last = div( lastBitNumber, bitsInWord );
std::fill( array.begin(), array.begin() + first.quot, 0 );
if ( first.quot == last.quot ) {
    array[ first.quot ] &= ((1 << last.rem) - 1) & ~((i << first.rem) - 1);
} else {
    array[ first.quot ] &= ~((i << first.rem) - 1);
    array[ last.quot ] &= ((1 << last.rem) - 1);
}
std::fill( array.begin() + last.quot + 1, array.end(), 0 );
```

You'll probably need some casts with the shift operators, in
order to ensure they use the full size of the array elements.
And of course, you definitely want to ensure that first and last
are in bounds before any of this.